# How can I show text with different language direction in GTK+?

Tags: gtk, pango

I need to show some text in Arabic (which is right-to-left) and some other text in English (which is left-to-right) in the same GTK+ windows. Is there any way to set the language to the GktLabel instead of the application?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with [`gtk_widget_set_direction`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-direction):

```
label = gtk_label_new ("Hello World");
gtk_widget_set_halign (label, GTK_ALIGN_START);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), label);

label = gtk_label_new ("برنامج أهلا بالعالم");
gtk_widget_set_halign (label, GTK_ALIGN_START);
gtk_widget_set_direction (label, GTK_TEXT_DIR_RTL);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), label);
```

[image: Screenshot]